# What is the Swift equivalent of C#/.NET/LINQ's Enumerable.All method?

Tags: swift, functional-programming

I want a function that applies a given function to a sequence and returns true iff the given function returns true for every element of the sequence, like [Enumerable.All](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb548541.aspx) from the C#/.NET/LINQ world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a built-in function to do this, but you can easily add your own as a protocol extension method:

```
extension SequenceType {
    func all(@noescape predicate: (Self.Generator.Element) throws -> Bool)
        rethrows -> Bool {

        for i in self {
            if !(try predicate(i)) { return false }
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

and then use it on a sequence like:

```
let allPositive = [1, 2, 3].all { $0 > 0 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Building up on [Jon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35061151/1187415): You can use `contains()`
instead of an (explicit) loop:

```
extension SequenceType {
    func all(@noescape predicate: (Self.Generator.Element) throws -> Bool)
        rethrows -> Bool {
            return !(try contains { !(try predicate($0)) })
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah thank you. I didn't realise that the predicate version of contains() is like .NET's Enumerable.Any(). That's very useful to know too :)

Comment: I just thought I should say that I decided to accept my answer rather than this one because I think it's a tiny bit more readable. I think the double negative in this one makes it a little harder to understand quickly. Thank you again for the answer, though :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, but you can achieve the same outcome using `reduce`. Here's a quick playground I put together to prove the concept:

```
let nums = [2, 2, 3, 4]

// Will only evaluate to true if all numbers are even.
let allEven = nums.reduce(true) {
    if !$0 || $1 % 2 != 0 {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: A possible disadvantage is that `reduce()` always traverses the entire sequence, whereas `contains()` returns as soon as a matching element is found. That may or may not be relevant. – Note that you can simplify the code to `nums.reduce(true) { $0 && ($1 % 2 == 0) }`.

Comment: Nice - I knew someone would come up with a more succinct version.