# What are Swift's counterparts to JavaScript's Array.some() and Array.every()?

Tags: arrays, swift, list-comprehension

Swift provides `map`, `filter`, `reduce`, ... for `Array`'s, but I am not finding `some` (or `any`) or `every` (or `all`) whose counterparts in JavaScript are [`Array.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [`Array.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every). Am I not looking hard enough or do they exist?

A [related question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35061150/what-is-the-swift-equivalent-of-c-net-linqs-enumerable-all-method) is looking for the Swift `all` method, but JS programmers will probably not find it (there is no `all` in JS and `some` or `any` is not mentioned).

Comment: As far as i know they are not implemented and you have to implement them yourself. Altough i might be wrong

Comment: @eric-d I couldn't figure out how to reimplement with `filter` etc... and have them short-circuit (i.e., stop when the result is known).

Comment: "some" is `contains()`. For "every" see for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35061150/what-is-the-swift-equivalent-of-c-net-linqs-enumerable-all-method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To replace `any`/`some`, you can use SequenceType's [`contains`](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_SequenceType_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/intfm/SequenceType/s:FEsPs12SequenceType8containsFzFzWx9Generator7Element_SbSb) method (there's one version which takes a boolean predicate; the other one takes an element and works only for sequences of Equatable elements).

There's no built-in function like `all`/`every`, but you can easily write your own using an extension:

```
extension SequenceType
{
    /// Returns `true` iff *every* element in `self` satisfies `predicate`.
    func all(@noescape predicate: Generator.Element throws -> Bool) rethrows -> Bool
    {
        for element in self {
            if try !predicate(element) {
                return false
            }
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

Or, thanks to [De Morgan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), you can just negate the result of `contains`: `!array.contains{ !predicate($0) }`.

By the way, these work on any SequenceType, not just Array. That includes Set and even Dictionary (whose elements are `(key, value)` tuples).

Comment: Thanks -- it looks like `contains` is the ticket for both issues (I am still trying to wrap my head around your sequence extension code).

Comment: Feel free to ask about anything confusing. I wrote a [blog post](https://bandes-stor.ch/blog/2015/11/28/help-yourself-to-some-swift/) a while back that covers a little bit about extensions, which might help; the official docs are [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html).

Comment: Just read about `@noescape` ... it looks like Swift will take awhile to master.

Answer (score 8):

**Update:**

Use [allSatisfy](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2994715-allsatisfy) (`all`) and [contains(where:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2297359-contains) (`some`).

**Old answer:**

Just use [contains](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2945493-contains).

```
// check if ALL items are completed
// so it does not contain a single item which is not completed
!items.contains { !$0.completed }

// check if SOME item is completed
// so test if there is at least one item which is completed
items.contains { $0.completed }
```

Comment: Shouldn't the SOME expression be `$0.completed == true`?

Comment: i checked if there is no item completed. this was confusing. i improved the answer.