# Are `Any` and `All` functions with predicates already built-in or do I need to roll my own?

Tags: swift

I wrote this code because I couldn't figure out if I could leverage what's already available in Swift 2 to do the same:

```
extension Array {

    func any(predicate: (Element) -> Bool) -> Bool {
        for element in self {
            if predicate(element) {
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }

    func all(predicate: (Element) -> Bool) -> Bool {
        for element in self {
            if !predicate(element) {
                return false
            }
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

Was I right to assume that way or can any of the existing functions cover these two cases?

Comment: What Eric said. Your `any` is just [`contains`](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_SequenceType_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/intfm/SequenceType/s:FEsPs12SequenceType8containsFzFzWx9Generator7Element_SbSb) and your `all` is `contains` with an inverted predicate (you can still write an extension with that logic).

Comment: For `all`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35061150/what-is-the-swift-equivalent-of-c-net-linqs-enumerable-all-method.